# How to change environment variables in python?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

i have a simple python script ( test.py ):

```
import cx_Oracle
from cx_Oracle
tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.10.1.3', 1521, 'etst')
db = cx_Oracle.connect('test', 'test', tns)
```

it is work if I run script with enviroument settings:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
./test.py
```

Can I set environment variables in python script ?

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib"
os.putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/")
```

not work.

Comment: I found a similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348894/deploying-cx-oracle-onto-various-versions-of-oracle-client

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set them that way, **however** `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is read by the loader which has already run before that therefore you *must* set that one externally beforehand.

Comment: Specifically, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't used by `cx_Oracle` but it's used to create the Python process. So it needs to be defined before the first byte of Python is executed.